# What's the best practise for Perl hashes with array values?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

What is the best practise to solve this?

```
    if (... ) 
   { 
    push (@{$hash{'key'}}, @array ) ; 
     }
    else 
     {
     $hash{'key'} =""; 
 }
```

Is that bad practise for storing one element is array or one is just double quote in hash?

Comment: Don't forget you need to add curly brackes `{}` around your if and else statement blocks. :-)

Comment: How are you going to use the entry with no value?  Would `undef` work, or would that cause confusion because you'll use `defined` to test the element.  Otherwise, you're likely to be using `ref` to identify whether you've got an array or a scalar.

Comment: Best practices require well-understood conditions. I think I've done *something* like what you're doing--but I have no idea what exactly you're doing or what "problem" you're solving by doing it. I have needed put push values onto an array in a hash, but I have never needed to store an empty string in a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll answer it literally as asked for now...

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my $arrayRef = \@array;     # alternatively: my $arrayRef = [1, 2, 3, 4];

my %hash;

$hash{'key'} = $arrayRef;   # or again: $hash{'key'} = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $hash{'key'} = \@array;
```

The crux of the problem is that arrays or hashes take scalar values... so you need to take a reference to your array or hash and use that as the value.

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

---

**EDIT:** Yes, you can add empty strings as values for some keys and references (to arrays or hashes, or even scalars, typeglobs/filehandles, or other scalars. Either way) for other keys. They're all still scalars.

You'll want to look at the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function for figuring out how to disambiguate between the reference types and normal scalars.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here (pun intended) by guessing it's because Tree didn't get exactly the answer he was looking for. I got a downvote on my answer as well. This is making me a lot more hesitant to answer any of Tree's questions from now on.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably simpler to use explicit array references:

```
my $arr_ref = \@array;
$hash{'key'} = $arr_ref;
```

Actually, doing the above and using `push` result in the same data structure:

```
my @array = qw/ one two three four five /;
my $arr_ref = \@array;
my %hash;
my %hash2;
$hash{'key'} = $arr_ref;
print Dumper \%hash;
push @{$hash2{'key'}}, @array;
print Dumper \%hash2;
```

This gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key' => [
                     'one',
                     'two',
                     'three',
                     'four',
                     'five'
                   ]
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'key' => [
                     'one',
                     'two',
                     'three',
                     'four',
                     'five'
                   ]
        };
```

Using explicit array references uses fewer characters and is easier to read than the `push @{$hash{'key'}}, @array` construct, IMO.

**Edit:** For your `else{}` block, it's probably less than ideal to assign an empty string. It would be a lot easier to just skip the `if-else` construct and, later on when you're accessing values in the hash, to do a `if( defined( $hash{'key'} ) )` check. That's a lot closer to standard Perl idiom, and you don't waste memory storing empty strings in your hash.

Instead, you'll have to use `ref()` to find out what kind of data you have in your value, and that is less clear than just doing a defined-ness check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but there are several things to consider.

First, if you are going to store an array, do you want to store a reference to the original value or a copy of the original values? In either case, I prefer to avoid the dereferencing syntax and take references when I can:

```
 $hash{key} = \@array;  # just a reference

 use Clone; # or a similar module
 $hash{key} = clone( \@array );
```

Next, do you want to add to the values that exist already, even if it's a single value? If you are going to have array values, I'd make all the values arrays even if you have a single element. Then you don't have to decide what to do and you remove a special case:

```
 $hash{key} = [] unless defined $hash{key};
 push @{ $hash{key} }, @values;
```

That might be your "best practice" answer, which is often the technique that removes as many special cases and extra logic as possible. When I do this sort of thing in a module, I typically have a `add_value` method that encapsulates this magic where I don't have to see it or type it more than once.

If you already have a non-reference value in the hash key, that's easy to fix too:

```
 if( defined $hash{key} and ! ref $hash{key} ) {
      $hash{key} = [ $hash{key} ];
      }
```

If you already have non-array reference values that you want to be in the array, you do something similar. Maybe you want an anonymous hash to be one of the array elements:

```
 if( defined $hash{key} and ref $hash{key} eq ref {} ) {
      $hash{key} = [ $hash{key} ];
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the revised notation:

```
if (... ) 
{ 
    push (@{$hash{'key'}}, @array); 
}
else 
{
    $hash{'key'} = "";
}
```

we can immediately tell that you are not following the standard advice that protects novices (and experts!) from their own mistakes.  You're using a symbolic reference, which is not a good idea.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ( key => "value" );
my @array = ( 1, "abc", 2 );
my @value = ( 22, 23, 24 );

push(@{$hash{'key'}}, @array);

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) { print "$key = $hash{$key}\n"; }
foreach my $value (@array)        { print "array $value\n"; }
foreach my $value (@value)        { print "value $value\n"; }
```

This does not run:

```
Can't use string ("value") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at xx.pl line 8.
```

I'm not sure I can work out what you were trying to achieve.  Even if you remove the 'use strict;' warning, the code shown does not detect a change from the `push` operation.

```
use warnings;

my %hash = ( key => "value" );
my @array = ( 1, "abc", 2 );
my @value = ( 22, 23, 24 );

push @{$hash{'key'}}, @array;

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash)   { print "$key = $hash{$key}\n"; }
foreach my $value (@array)          { print "array $value\n"; }
foreach my $value (@value)          { print "value $value\n"; }
foreach my $value (@{$hash{'key'}}) { print "h_key $value\n"; }

push @value, @array;

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) { print "$key = $hash{$key}\n"; }
foreach my $value (@array)        { print "array $value\n"; }
foreach my $value (@value)        { print "value $value\n"; }
```

Output:

```
key = value
array 1
array abc
array 2
value 22
value 23
value 24
h_key 1
h_key abc
h_key 2
key = value
array 1
array abc
array 2
value 22
value 23
value 24
value 1
value abc
value 2
```

I'm not sure what is going on there.

Comment: You get the error in the first one because you've already instantiated the `$hash{'key'}` value, so it becomes `"value"` when you refer to it. If it's not defined before you do the `push()`, Perl does what you want and does some crazy reference magic and makes an array reference as the value for `$hash{'key'}`.

Comment: @CanSpice: OK, I sort of see, through a glass darkly.  I get more or less what you suggest with `my %hash = ();`.  I know I don't want to know how it works; too contorted to be maintainable by me.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how do you *replace* a empty string value you had stored before with an array onto which you can push your values, this might be the best way to do it:

```
if ( ... ) { 
    my $r = \$hash{ $key }; # $hash{ $key } autoviv-ed
    $$r   = [] unless ref $$r;
    push @$$r, @values;
}
else { 
    $hash{ $key } = "";
}
```

- I avoid multiple hash look-ups by saving a copy of the auto-vivified slot.
- Note the code relies on a scalar or an array being the entire universe of things stored in `%hash`.